# Cyrillic symbols in paths failed with utf-8 in Gvim

Tags: vim, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to solve different problems in Gvim at Windows 10 for several days. Right now I'm trying to properly use utf-8 encoding. At last most messages and Gvim menu are set right. But runtimepaths are not. At the first image at place where arrow points should be written Анастасия in cyrilic letters. If I delete utf-8 settings from .vimrc, cyrilic symbols in pathes are set properly, but still paths look strange.

I need help very much.

My .vimrc:

```
if has("gui")
    "set guifont=Consolas:h12:cRUSSIAN:qDRAFT
    set guifont=Courier_New:h10
endif

set fileencoding=utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
set termencoding=utf-8
let $LANG = 'en'
set langmenu=en_EN.UTF-8
language messages en_EN.UTF-8
scriptencoding utf-8
source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim

call plug#begin('~/vimfiles/bundle')

Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips' | Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'

call plug#end()

set showcmd
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think your immediate problem is not the messed-up output in the error message, but the fact that there's a missing backslash between `C:\Users` and your Cyrilic user name.